# Is it safe to call remove() to delete files in destructor?

Tags: c++, exception, file-io, destructor, stdio

I have a class that creates a few temp files when certain member functions are called. I want those files to be removed whenever the class goes out of scope (normally or due to exception), so I'd like to remove them in the destructor:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
class MyClass
{
    //implementation details

    //Names of temp files
    std::string tempFile1, tempFile2,tempFile3;

    ~MyClass()
    {
         remove(tempFile1.c_str());
         remove(tempFile2.c_str());
         remove(tempFile3.c_str());
    }
};
```

The problem is that if the destructor is called due to an exception, then it is probable that not all the 3 temp files have been created. According to [cpluscplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/), in this case the `remove()` function will return a non-zero value and write something to stderr. But since it's a C function, there won't be an exception.

I know that destructors should not throw. What about errors like this? Is it recommended to write a destructor like this one?

Comment: Calling `remove()` will never write to stderr. The example at cplusplus.com writes to stderr if `remove()` fails, that's not the same as `remove()` doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have shown will work fine.  But I generally prefer a more RAII approach, eg:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

struct RemovableFile
{
    std::string fileName;
    bool canRemove;

    RemovableFile() : canRemove(false) {}
    ~RemovableFile(){ if (canRemove) remove(fileName.c_str()); }
};

class MyClass
{
    ...
    //Names of temp files
    RemovableFile tempFile1, tempFile2, tempFile3;
    ...
};

void MyClass::doSomething()
{
    ...
    tempFile1.fileName = ...;
    ...
    if (file was created)
        tempFile1.canRemove = true;
    ...
};
```

Or maybe something more like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct RemovableFile
{
    std::string  fileName;
    std::fstream file;

    ~RemovableFile() { if (file.is_open()) { file.close(); remove(fileName.c_str()); } }

    void createFile(const std::string &aFileName)
    {
        file.open(aFileName.c_str(), ...);
        fileName = aFileName;
    }
};

class MyClass
{
    ...
    //Names of temp files
    RemovableFile tempFile1, tempFile2, tempFile3;
    ...
};

void MyClass::doSomething()
{
    ...
    tempFile1.createFile(...);
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no interaction between the C library function `remove` and C++ destructors.

Not unless

- you're writing a C library, and doing it in C++, and the above `MyClass` is part of the implementation such that calling `remove` triggers some bad re-entrance or something.)
- you're doing this in a signal handler which went off during a call to the C library, in which case the C++ destructor aspect is moot. You can't call `remove` from a signal handler.
- you're throwing exceptions which cross C library activation frames. That could be bad.

The `remove` function most certainly does not print anything, even if it fails. You're misunderstanding the cplusplus.com reference text. It is referring to its code sample, not to the function. The code sample is what prints the message.

Comment: Yes I definitely misunderstood the reference. Thank you !